# I wish to fix this regex to match both blocks of text separately

Tags: c#, regex

```
@@IF[- (<>%='@a-z0-9\r\n\t).:!_,+/""]+(@@END IF|@ENDIF)
```

Hello I wish to fix the above regex to match both blocks of text separately using C#. At the moment it treats the below as a single match.

```
@@IF (<%=SHOPCODE%> == '2' ) THEN
return complicated if 
@@ELSE
Boo
@@END IF 

!

@@IF (<%=SHOPCODE%> == '1' )  THEN
County is UK
@@ELSE
Not UK
@@END IF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try capturing groups along with *Lazy* way.

```
(@@IF\b[\S\s]*?\r?\n@@?END ?IF)
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hM8aF5/3)

Regex explanation: (as per your need you can change optional)

```
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    @@IF                     '@@IF'
    \b                       the word boundary
    [\S\s]*?                 any character (0 or more times (least possible))
    \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional)
    \n?                      '\n' (newline)
    @                        '@'
    @?                       '@' (optional)
    END                      'END'
     ?                       ' ' (optional)
    IF                       'IF'
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: `\r?\n?` is useless, `\n` would be better, or `^` with `RegexOptions.Multiline`.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I don't know which will work that's why I used both `\r` and `\n`. I have suggested to change the optional as per the need.

Comment: `\r` can be matched by the `\s` earlier in the expression, so you can leave it out. And if you leave the `?` quantifier on `\n`, it becomes redundant. Matching against a newline is a good idea, but I'd enforce it by removing the `?`. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski In this case you're right because we don't need to isolate the previous characters from the newline (it doesn't matter if the previous expression `[\S\s]*?` swallows a `\r` or not). But generally when you want to capture newlines (and can't be sure of the format of your input string) you do need `\r?`. .NET regex does not automatically handle this, even with the `Multiline` option; the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Multiline) recommends `\r?$`.

Comment: @nmclean Now I am confused. I have a little knowledge about regex not specific to any language that's why I have suggested both. thanks for documentation.

Comment: @nmclean Yes `\r?\n` is more appropriate for the general case. I should have pointed it out.

Comment: +1 for the free-spacing version. Regarding the line break story, there are lots of subtleties you come to love, for instance `\R` and `\N` in Perl and PCRE, as well as where the `$` matches in relation to the closing line breaks etc. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another case of greediness...

Use [non-greedy quantifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx) (and simplify the regex):

```
@@IF\s+.*?(?:@@END IF|@ENDIF)
```

Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/kV0tM5/1

The part `.*?` will match *as few characters as possible*.

Comment: @Jaycee Use `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Comment: Sorry I need multiline or will that not matter?

Comment: @Jaycee It will not matter. This option is badly named for historical reasons. The only thing it does it letting `.` match a newline.

Comment: @Jaycee Why don't you try my option? :)

Comment: Well... Your option is almost the same. `[\S\s]` is the equivalent of `.` under `RegexOptions.Singleline`. :)

Comment: I tried both, excellent, they work. Not sure which to use, I like Braj's better because it work with multiline and ignore case options I already had set. Lucas explanation was better though.

Comment: @Jaycee Both are equivalent, except for tiny edge cases. Use the one you're most comfortable with.